# JS variable reference error

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple native js application seems to work, but i have noticed something interesting while i been stepping through the debuger in my browser[image]

It says my var id not defined? i understand what i means i would expect to see this in console, but in debugger?

```
var playerScore = [0,0];
var player = 0;
var score = 0;
var troll = 0;

function rollDice() {
  var dice = 0;
  dice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  return dice;
}

function playerTurn() {
  player === 0 ? player = 1 : player = 0;
  // score = 0;
}

function turnScore() {
  rollDice() !== 1 ? score += rollDice() : playerTurn();
  return score;
}

function gameScore() {
  troll = playerScore[player] += turnScore();
  return troll
}

document.getElementById('rollDice').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('round-score-' + player).innerHTML = turnScore();
});
document.getElementById('saveScore').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('score-' + player).innerHTML = gameScore();
});
document.getElementById('newGame').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('score-1').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('round-score-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('round-score-1').textContent = '0';
});
```

Can someone explain what is happening thx

Comment: The current debug pointer is inside another function where dice is out of scope since it is a variable local to `rollDice()`. I'd imagine this is why you're seeing the message.

Comment: owww ok I see so my debugger is also stopping at this function `turnScore()` so the `var dice` is not declared there but is in `rollDice()`  but i only want this variable to be in rollDice function as i will only use it there i need the function return. seems like its a error i can ignore but at the same time still wondering what is the best approach

Comment: But you're also using `troll` inside only one function, so if this is the way you're planning on formatting your code, I'd recommend declaring `dice` at the start as the other variables. Otherwise I'd recommend making a constructor (or class) of the whole thing and have the variables as properties and functions as methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call rollDice() that dice will not declare and initialize. If you call rollDice() function you may calling dice from out of it's scope dice is a local variable it only can be access within the rollDice() function.Use following to get the return value

var anotherVariable = rollDice();